# equivalent of mysql_affected_rows in ODBC

Tags: php, sql, odbc

i am using odbc connection to connect with MS-SQL server 2008. Now i need to confirm that a UPDATE command is executed properly into the database.In generally we use mysql_affected_rows to identify the affected rows.Now what is the corresponding odbc function to get the value?
i have used the "odbc_num_rows" ,but it's not working properly. Can anybody suggest ?My sample code is below:

```
$update_query="UPDATE testtable SET  col1='$abc',col2='$def' WHERE id='$id'";                                   
odbc_exec($cn,$update_query);
$val= odbc_num_rows($cn);
echo "Val: ".$val;exit; 
if($val>0){
//Do someting
}
```

Here value is update properly into the database. But i don't get any proper confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the result of `odbc_exec` to `odbc_num_rows`;

```
$result = odbc_exec($cn,$update_query);
$val= odbc_num_rows($result);
```